# Draw ContextMenuStrip over taskbar

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, contextmenu

I wonder if there is some way to draw elements over taskbar?

For example, I have application which shows some context menu at bottom left corner of the screen. I tried `ContextMenu` and `ContextMenuStrip`, and I would like to use the second one. `ContextMenu` is drawing over taskbar, but `ContextMenuStrip` is not - it is just shown some pixels above the taskbar.

Is there a way to draw `ContextMenuStrip` over taskbar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to find an answer. ContextMenuStrip has [internal ShowInTaskbar method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ContextMenuStrip.cs,8d05938cf5032776,references):

```
internal void ShowInTaskbar(int x, int y)
```

It can not be used in usual way, but it can be invoked (which is usually not recommended, because it can cause some errors in thread sequential logic). Still if you want to use some internal or private classes' methods, you can do it in following way:

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(ContextMenuStrip).GetMethod("ShowInTaskbar", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
mi.Invoke(contextMenuStrip1, new object[] { mousePositionX, mousePositionY });
```

You just have to send correct menu strip and mouse coordinates, in order to show menu in proper position.

After using this method my contextMenuStip1 was shown over Taskbar!